# export excel data to sql.spreadsheetcontrol in dev express

Tags: c#, excel, devexpress

i have recently started using devexpress and was inquiring how i can set up my program to export excel data to sql database as well as check for any changes to the excel worksheet(spreadsheetcontrol) and update the respective tables in the sql database.
P.S I have already bound the sql tables to excel worksheet and i can veiw sql data from an excel work sheet using the following code

```
private void BindToDataSource()
{
    Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[6];
    worksheet.DataBindings.BindToDataSource(dataView, 1, 1);
}

private void CreateDataSource()
{
    voluntary_dbDataSet ds = new voluntary_dbDataSet();
    voluntary_dbDataSetTableAdapters.CollectionsTableAdapter coladpter = new voluntary_dbDataSetTableAdapters.CollectionsTableAdapter();
    coladpter.Fill(ds.Collections);


    dataView = new DataView(ds.Collections);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go through documentation - [Data Binding](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/117679/Controls-and-Libraries/Spreadsheet/Data-Binding). Along this you can find [Data Binding examples](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/117779/Controls-and-Libraries/Spreadsheet/Examples/Data-Binding).

```
// Create a "Products" DataTable object.
DataTable sourceTable = new DataTable("Products");
sourceTable.Columns.Add("Product", typeof(string));
sourceTable.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(float));
sourceTable.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(Int32));

sourceTable.Rows.Add("Chocolade", 5, 15);
sourceTable.Rows.Add("Konbu", 9, 55);
sourceTable.Rows.Add("Geitost", 15, 70);

// Bind the worksheet to the created DataTable.
worksheet.DataBindings.BindToDataSource(sourceTable, 1, 1);
```

**References:**
[Add the capability to bind the Spreadsheet control to a Data Source (two-way datasource binding)](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/S172901/add-the-capability-to-bind-the-spreadsheet-control-to-a-data-source-two-way-datasource)